# Unity - how to make object ignore ray cast

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine, game-physics, raycasting

I have a game object (lets say `Enemy`) and it has an `Audio Trigger` script on it with a `Sphere Collider`.

Now the attack system uses `Ray Casting` to detect the layer however when you point on an enemy that has an `Audio Trigger` on it with a `Sphere Collider` the `Ray casting` dont recognize it. How do you solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1st of all many thanks to Ben Tristten I took the answer from one of his aswome courses.

On your `Audio Trigger` script (or a script that is on top of the game object you want to ray cast to). add the following line to the `Start()` or `Awake()` method :

```
gameObject.layer = LayerMask.NameToLayer ("Ignore Raycast");
```

Hope this helps anyone who struggles with this :)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Rony_y's answer, it should be noted that the [`Physics.Raycast()` method](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html) (as well as other similar methods, such as RaycastAll, SphereCast, and so on) takes a `LayerMask` parameter in one of its overloads.

This parameter lets you specify *what layers you want to raycast against* as a [bitmask](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_(computing)) (so casting against the Default layer only would be done by passing a `1`, while casting against Default and Layer 8--the first layer that you can name--would be done by passing `257`: eg. `1<<8 + 1<<0`).

In this way you can set up your objects to have different physics layers as needed (up to 32 different layers, the first 8 of which are not renamable), for example all of your audio collider volumes can have their  own `Audio` layer that you can then just not include in your raycasts.

Comment: Thanks for the addition.